# NPE on fragment recreation. Button is null after orientation change in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have read all the other topics related to this issue and none seem to be helping me solve the problem.

I am doing some background task in an asynctask that needs to persist on orientation change (configChanges). I have gotten the data to persist I believe by using fragments and setRetainInstance(true), but my buttons (Im assuming any views really) are being set to null on recreation of the fragment on orientation change. This is causing a null pointer error when I try to operate on the buttons reference after orientation has change (fragment has been recreated).

I have tried wrapping the button and calls on the button in a statement to check if the bundle is null. This stops the crash but does not allow for the button to be used again on recreation of the fragment.

The following class extends Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    currentActivity = super.getActivity();

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated(Bundle)");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    simpleForecastIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, SimpleForecastActivity.class);

    Button fetchDataButton = (Button) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.fetchDataButton);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fetchDataButton.setOnClickListener(fetchDataButtonListener);
        fetchDataButton.setTransformationMethod(null);
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager)
            currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (isTaskRunning) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(currentActivity, "Fetching data", "Please wait...");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,  Bundle)");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, container, false);
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locationField"
            android:text="@string/fetch_weather_data"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locationField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/enter_location"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/previousLocationsList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fetchDataButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have spent far too many hours on something so trivial and really need a bump in the correct direction. How can I get the button to not be null on recreation of fragment?

**EDIT SOLVED:**
I was using the disposed of activity's context to find the view of the button. Instead of the new activities view context.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        currentActivity = super.getActivity();

    }
```

Comment: Is the button created in OnResume()?

Comment: Is the button a part of your activity, or part of the fragment view?

Comment: No Al, I have tried this and it causes the same problem. John it is part of my fragment.

Comment: `currentActivity = super.getActivity();` will not be true after configuration change when `setRetainInstance(true)` was called. Memory leaks all the way.

Comment: Yep Eugen. Dont know why it took me so long to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing your button in `onActivityCreated` instead of `onCreateView`.  On orientation change, the view gets torn down and then recreated.  You should override `onCreateView` and maintain the reference to your button from there.

UPDATE:

I see how your code is working, but in my opinion it's following a bad design pattern.  You are still instantiating your view references inside of onActivityCreated, instead of immediately after they are inflated in onCreateView.

I would switch it to something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,  Bundle)");

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, container, false);

    Button fetchDataButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.fetchDataButton);
    ...

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Yes this made sense to me as well. But I tried this earlier and again just now and it causes the same error but sooner. I dont even have to change orientations when it is in onCreateView and the error is thrown. I have tried it as both a global reference and local aswell in both of these methods.

Comment: how are you inflating your fragment's view in onCreateView?  My guess is that you are referencing the activity for the button lookup instead of the inflated view returned in `onCreateView`.  Might be worth it to post your `onCreateView` code.

Comment: Well John your comment was not the problem, but it got me thinking about context and I see my problem now and have fixed it. So I will accept your answer.

Comment: Yes thank you John. I was trying to do that aswell. Thanks for the help. Im new to Android but even newer to fragments and their lifecycles. Just bought a book to read up on it.